# remove facebook referrer via tag manager

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I want to solve the common facebook referrer issue with google analytics.

The problem is that when someone logs in from facebook login the source / medium attribute in google analytics is set to **facebook / referral** due to facebook.com document.referrer.

I have implemented a custom javascript function named JS referral excluder in tag manager like this:

```
function() {

var hname = {{Referrer}};
console.log('referrer value: ' + hname);

if (hname) {  
    if (hname.indexOf('facebook') > -1 && window.location.href.indexOf('via=facebook') > -1 ){
        console.log('return null referrer');
        return null;
     }   
}

console.log('nothing found, return referrer');
return {{Referrer}};

}
```

So according to above code when referrer is **facebook** and current page contains **via=facebook** string then do not return referrer.

After i added this variable to default referrer variable in tag manager as shown below 
[image]

But analytics is still recording facebook.com as referral.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are there any additional tags that fire on the page?  If you don't replace all referrer references from the GA hits then that could cause a problem.

Comment: Can you copy the value of the hit that it sent and just X out any user IDs or property IDs? Ie, the google-analytics.com/r/collect value

Comment: @PatGrady so you are saying that i have to set the referrer value to my JS referral excluder custom function in every single tag that is fired on this page and not only in the Universal Analytics one?

Comment: @CarlK sorry i dont quite understand what you mean (i am not a heavy ga user). can you please elaborate?

Comment: The hit is the network event that is sent to Google. It can be seen in the network tab of Chrome Developer Tools if you filter for /collect/. It will contain a number of parameters in the URL. Specifically, there is a &dr parameter that I am curious to see what the value actually is in the hit

Comment: @CarlK just tested that. no dr parameter included,maybe you mean dt , dl or dt. Anyway thanks for the help. I have made like 50 test but no luck in excluding facebook referrer via tag manager

Comment: Get the GA Debugger extension from chrome and check in witch hit this information is being send.

Comment: Ok problem solved! It seems that tag manager was a mess and had double tags and double variables. I removed everyhing that was not needed and worked like a charm :)